# Are execution times of these SQL queries the same?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I believe the result obtained by these 2 queries is the same?

The first query:

```
SELECT 
  sensor_id,
  measurement_time,
  measurement_value
FROM 
  public.measurement_pm2_5
  WHERE (sensor_id = 12 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(3000) AND to_timestamp(12000))
  OR (sensor_id = 27 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(3000) AND to_timestamp(12000))
  OR (sensor_id = 1 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(500) AND to_timestamp(1000))
  OR (sensor_id = 1 AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(6000) AND to_timestamp(9000));
```

The second query:

```
SELECT 
  sensor_id,
  measurement_time,
  measurement_value
FROM 
  public.measurement_pm2_5
  WHERE (sensor_id in (12,27) AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(3000) AND to_timestamp(12000))
  OR (sensor_id = 1 AND ((measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(500) AND to_timestamp(1000)) OR (measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(6000) AND to_timestamp(9000))));
```

How about execution time? How big is the difference (if any)?

The first query:

```
Start-up Cost: 0
Total Cost: 580.56
Number of Rows: 1
Row Width: 18
Start-up Time: 2.676
Total Time: 2.676
Real Number of Rows: 0
Loops: 1

Hash Join  (cost=0.10..280.06 rows=115 width=18) (actual time=8.596..8.596 rows=0 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (p.sensor_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
  Join Filter: ((p.measurement_time >= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column2)::double precision)) AND (p.measurement_time <= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column3)::double precision)))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 590
  ->  Seq Scan on measurement_pm2_5 p  (cost=0.00..207.39 rows=12439 width=18) (actual time=0.010..2.558 rows=12443 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=4 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=4 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.148 ms
Execution time: 8.627 ms
```

The second query:

```
Start-up Cost: 0
Total Cost: 456.17
Number of Rows: 1
Row Width: 18
Start-up Time: 2.237
Total Time: 2.237
Real Number of Rows: 0
Loops: 1

Hash Join  (cost=0.10..280.06 rows=115 width=18) (actual time=8.596..8.596 rows=0 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (p.sensor_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
  Join Filter: ((p.measurement_time >= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column2)::double precision)) AND (p.measurement_time <= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column3)::double precision)))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 590
  ->  Seq Scan on measurement_pm2_5 p  (cost=0.00..207.39 rows=12439 width=18) (actual time=0.010..2.558 rows=12443 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=4 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=4 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.148 ms
Execution time: 8.627 ms
```

@Mike's query:

```
Hash Join  (cost=0.10..280.06 rows=115 width=18) (actual time=8.596..8.596 rows=0 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (p.sensor_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
  Join Filter: ((p.measurement_time >= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column2)::double precision)) AND (p.measurement_time <= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column3)::double precision)))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 590
  ->  Seq Scan on measurement_pm2_5 p  (cost=0.00..207.39 rows=12439 width=18) (actual time=0.010..2.558 rows=12443 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=4 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=4 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.148 ms
Execution time: 8.627 ms
```

The question is, if the difference in time execution between these two queries is significant when these queries are made on large database?

Comment: If you want to know the execution time of two queries, then run the queries on your data, on your database, on your system.  That will give you the answer for the question you are asking.

Comment: Check the execution plan using `explain (analyze)`

Comment: If the execution time doesn't matter, why are you asking us?

Comment: I ran tests and execution times of both queries are about 62 ms. But I asked the question here because maybe that would change if the database grows and I thought that because the results of the queries are the same it would be system independent question.

Comment: Show us both execution plans - otherwise that is impossible to answer

Comment: try to get plan of query in my answer. "total cost" in plan is the answer to your question.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: The execution plans are exactly the same so I wouldn't expect any difference between them if the number of rows changes - but that can only be answered if you actually run them against a database with more data. The choices the query optimizer takes can not be predicted for an unknown data set

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT 
  sensor_id,
  measurement_time,
  measurement_value
FROM 
  public.measurement_pm2_5 p,
  ( values(12,3000,12000),(27,3000,12000),(1,500,1000),(1,6000,9000) ) as t(sens,t1,t2)
  WHERE p.sensor_id = t.sens
    AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(t.t1) AND to_timestamp(t.t2);
```

This decision is usually faster than any `OR` and `IN`

Answer (score 1):

EXPLAIN ANALYZE // paste first query here

eg: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from employee;`

you will get full explanation about your query and time taken by each sub query in details.